# Stream and file_put_content

Tags: php, file-io, stream

I have this code and work fine on localhost but on server give me error:

Warning: stream_get_contents() [function.stream-get-contents]: stream does not support seeking in /home/pluspon/public_html/get.php on line 41

Warning: stream_get_contents() [function.stream-get-contents]: Failed to seek to position 0 in the stream in /home/pluspon/public_html/get.php on line 41

CODE:

```
$site = fopen('http://www.google.com', 'r');
$store = 'store.php';
$stream__ = stream_get_contents($site, -1, 0);

file_put_contents($store, $stream__, LOCK_EX);
fclose($site);
$check = file_get_contents($store);

# var_dump($check); print_r($check); var_export($check); 
# or simple... 

echo $check;
```

wHAt that error means and how to fix that!

Comment: Do these errors output on screen or apache error log? Remove the 0 within stream_get_contents($site,-1). It is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you can't just do:

```
file_put_contents($store, file_get_contents('http://google.com'));
```

instead? Since you're fetching the whole contents of the specified url, there's no point in using the stream mechanism - you're not fetching only a part, you're not using anything other than a GET request, no authentication, etc...

Comment: What are you talking about? He straight up told you that you are making successive, unnecessary calls. Set $check to his code and run with it.

Comment: There is no point? I don't know about that. If the content is bigger than the RAM there is a point to do it in parts.